# Google Analytics Slows Down Android App

Tags: android, google-analytics

I've recently added Google Analytics to my Android app with the EasyTracker. However, I feel like my app has slowed down significantly since I added these. Is there a preferred method for dealing with this? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation for Analytics...

Here is what I put in the Activities I am tracking:

```
 @Override
  public void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      EasyTracker tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance();
      tracker.setContext(this);
      tracker.activityStart(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
      super.onStop();
      EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);
  }
```

Should I just send these to an AsyncTask? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's dispatching the results too quick.
Try setting the [dispatch time](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced#dispatch) to something longer, lets say 5 minutes (300 seconds).

Comment: But isn't the default 30min? I haven't set the dispatch period anywhere. I'll try this though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this guy's class: http://blog.tomgibara.com/post/5598222730/improving-android-google-analytics-performance

Hopefully this helps someone else as well!